# Levels of truth (is the liar paradox generated by equivocation?)

Tags: truth, paradox, properties

Strictly, Tarski's notion of truth levels, which is based on truth as a predicate (property), has it so that the liar sentence, "This sentence is false," by trying to attach a truth predicate from a higher-level language to a sentence in a lower-level language, violates the principle of separation for the levels. Or, the liar paradox is a premise in an argument for the levels being separated.

However, one might also say that the liar sentence does not generate a contradiction when denied (or affirmed), because it can be framed in a Tarski-inspired (though not strictly Tarskian) way as, "This sentence is false<sub>*n*</sub>," so that the act of denying it would be, "'This sentence is false<sub>*n*</sub>,' is false<sub>*n*+1</sub>." The local [revenge sentence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/liar-paradox/#ExprPoweReve) might be, "This sentence on truth level *n* is false<sub>*n*</sub>," which either goes to show that the separation principle can be stipulatively (ostensively) violated, or that which level a sentence is on, and what level of truth predicate can supposedly be stipulatively assigned to a sentence on whichever level, is not really a matter open to being decided by stipulation, in the end.<sup>†</sup>

Now the Tarskian doctrine, I will reiterate, adverts to the notion of truth as a predicate/property. [Frege famously proposed that a sentence is not true by having the truth as a property of the sentence, but by the sentence referring to "the True."](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-values/) Some other ways to cash this out in natural language (here, English) would be to speak of truth as a subject (of which true sentences are predicated) or truth as an object (truth being a sort of substance, and true sentences being properties attaching (in various ways that properties do, e.g. inherently) to this substance).

It seems to me, though, that if there is a truth value, there must be a function mapping sentences to this value, or which outputs this value when given various sentential inputs. And every function involves operations/operators (by pure definition, as when introducing the function means introducing the operation; or by characteristic expression, as when a function is "built up from" operators and input positions/variables), so that the idea of truth as a [prosentential operator](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-deflationary/#Pros) appears. (In this case, "It is true that..." is akin to, "It is known that..." from epistemic logic or, "It ought to be that..." from deontic logic.) Also, it's not clear to me that truth being a referent isn't explicable in terms of truth being a property, since other properties can also be referents.

At any rate, there seem to be possibly possible (so to speak) other "descriptions" of truth: truth as a part of every true sentence (the part that makes the sentence true); truth as a whole of which other true sentences are parts; truth as a set such that it is only possible to add elements to this set if the set 'makes' these elements (sentences) true; truth as an element of a sentence (in a sentence as a set, somehow) that justifies calling the sentence/set "true"; truth as a category; truth as a type of which true sentences are tokens (supposing this is not interchangeable with truth as a property); truth as a special cause (of which true sentences are the effects); truth as a special effect (caused by true sentences); and so on and on: indeed, what is there to stop us from "imagining" that there is a truth this-or-that for any sufficiently general/universal/deep other that-or-this? The universal depth of truth itself suggests such a thing, in my eyes.

**If there are not just different levels of truth predicates, but different levels of truth "terms" more generally, then does the argument from the liar sentence, to the elder paradox, rely on equivocation?** (That truth as a predicate is mighty different from truth as an operator, can be illustrated modulo the disquotation scheme, which allows us to take second-order sentences and disquote them down to a first-order estate; by contrast, "is true" in, "This sentence is true," isn't dispelled by a disquotation operation on that sentence.) It seems, to me, that when we move from, "This sentence is false," to, "'This sentence is false,' is true," this is covertly as if to say, "It is true that this sentence is false," which then becomes, "It is operationally true that this sentence is predicatively false." However, unless being true in terms of any one level is accompanied by being true in terms of any other level,<sup>††</sup> I don't see why the liar sentence couldn't be predicatively false and operationally true at the same time without there being an actual "contradiction" as a result.<sup>†††</sup> And there seems to be no prevalid revenge sentence available: "This sentence is operationally false," has to be rewritten as, "It is false that [something]," and at the very least I'm having a heck of a time filling in that [something] in a sufficiently vengeful way.

<sup>†</sup><sub>As if to say that, "This sentence is false," and, "This sentence is *defined* as false," are interchangeable.</sub>

<sup>††</sup><sub>It's not clear to me at all that every sentence would have to be true or false in terms of every possible level. Suppose that some sentences can be true or false, but only in terms of a truth operator. Perhaps this is "how" canonical sentences in fiction work (they are made true somehow by the logical *fiat* of applying the truth operator to them; but since fictional names don't refer to real objects, fictional canon sentences aren't true by referring to the True; and so on and on).</sub>

<sup>†††</sup><sub>The LNC could even be reformulated/refined as: *no sentence is true and false in terms of any one level*; *no sentence is true on as many levels as it is false*; *even if a sentence can be both true and false on some levels, it cannot be true and false on every level*; etc. In other words, what seems like a simple if dubious rule, i.e. ~(A&~A), is transformed into something much more subtle and evocative.</sub>

Comment: An ancient classic (said to make many people enlightened) discussing about truth and wisdom called [Surangama sutra](http://www.cttbusa.org/shurangama/shurangama17.asp.html) hinted: *To speak of the false is to reveal the true...*. So similar to Socrates' dialectic method, we can assertively find true theorems via proof by contradiction (false) logical inferences in an iteratively manner, but we cannot easily define the non-trivial primitive truth as they must be taken as some additional axioms in logic. Latest theories of truth seen SEP [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth/)...

Comment: Maybe this is the "solution" developed into *Principia Mathematica*'s theory of types (see "typical ambiguity").

Comment: I think not. [IEP, Liar](https://iep.utm.edu/par-liar/#H2) describes even more proposed interpretations and resolutions, Tarskian and others. For equivocation one plays on two different but definitive senses of a term, and the argument turns on the difference. In the case of the Liar there are multitudes of senses that can be assigned, and until they are it does not even make sense to talk whether the senses used within the argument are different or not. Some interpretations may make it equivocal, but most do not.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I was inspired by Tarskian talk of levels, which applies to a Russellian hierarchy of types, too, but I have had cause to think that it would have been better to talk of "truth departments" instead. I don't mean to say that the different truth terms are all clearly commensurable with each other. For example, saying that a sentence is true in terms of a truth-part doesn't seem to be on a higher or lower level than saying that a sentence is true in terms of a truth-cause. There might be hierarchies involving subsets of terms [cont]

Comment: [cont] for example, truth as a cause might be "prior" to truth as an effect, or truth as a part is before truth as a whole, or whatever else along such lines, but the general array of truth terms doesn't seem to have to be hierarchical. At any rate, I haven't found any argument in this system establishing such a hierarchy, and the "there is a truth term for every fundamental other kind of term" might even testify *against* an absolute hierarchy, here.